# MVC 5 - Populate Details in Partial View from the Parent View and Save record to the Parent ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am fairly new to MVC and I'm trying to build what seems like a complex data model with a code first DbContext approach.

I have a customer which I want to add multiple surveys to.

I'll explain my view setup as simply as I can. This is what the view looks like:

Customer (Displays a table with a list of customers, which contains create, edit, view and delete links that links to normal views.

When I click on view, it takes me to a normal view page. On this page I have two partial view tabs titled customer and surveys.

When I click on the surveys tab it should show a table with a list of surveys containing create, edit, view and delete links that should link to popup modal partial views.

The main question here is how do I send the ID of the customer in the view to the new survey so that it can link the survey ID to my customer ID and also automatically fill in some customer details on my survey for example the customer name.

If you need any more info I would be happy to supply it.

Thank you

Comment: You can send the id via querystring.

Answer (score 0):

In the part where you now have your Create/Read/Edit/Delete links, add in a parameter in the link like

```
/Edit/CustomerId={customerId}
```

Now you can get that parameter in the postback to your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int customerId)
```